# How can I load a single tensor from a checkpoint file in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load a tensor stored in a saved checkpoint file. The checkpoints are saved in "V2 format." 
Example: "checkpoint-100000.data-00000-of-00001" and "checkpoint-100000.index." 
**There is no .meta file**

All the resources available online point to the .meta file as the essential file to load into a session, but I don't have that as an option.

I just want to be able to view the dimensions of my tensor and maybe do some analysis on them. For example, when I run "print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file()" one of my larger tensors has an ellipses so I've lost a lot of columns / information and I want to recover the raw size.

A snippet from a large tensor with ellipses:

```
[[[-4.60817486e-01 -3.75553429e-01 -8.64749104e-02 ... -1.25204027e-03
 -1.03347138e-01 -3.74164522e-01]
```

Comment: Do you have the code to build the same graph?
If so, build the graph and then create a saver with `tf.train.Saver` then load the weights with `saver.restore`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tf.train.load_variable`, e.g.

```
x=tf.train.load_variable('/home/user/logdir/checkpoint', 'variable_name')
```

Also useful: you can get the names of the variables in a checkpoint with `tf.train.list_variables()`